# Using saved card details for MOTO payments

Tags: stripe-payments, e-commerce

Does anyone know if you're allowed to use saved card details for MOTO payments?

The scenario is this.

- Customer calls in.
- Agent brings up customer details
- Agent see that the customer has saved cards already on their account
- Agent selects saved card
- Agent uses that to start the payment (I believe CCV details will need to be
  added to complete payment)

It was my understanding that all card details need to be keyed in (card number/date/CCV).

In my case, we're using Stripe API, but I'm more concerned about the rules of the process in general.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to process MOTO payments with the Stripe API, you first need to [contact Stripe](https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true) to enable that feature as explained [here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/mail-order-telephone-order-moto-transactions-when-to-categorize-transactions-as-moto). Otherwise, if your account is in the European Economic Area, payments made by manually entering card details in the Dashboard will be automatically marked as MOTO by Stripe.

However, as mentioned on [this support page](https://support.stripe.com/questions/enter-customer-payment-information-manually-into-stripe-for-mail-or-telephone-orders), note that:

- You’re responsible for ensuring that you protect your customers’ card information in accordance with PCI compliance requirements.
- Manually creating payments through the Dashboard must only be performed when there are exceptional circumstances preventing you from using your own integration. It cannot be your primary method of processing payments on your account.

Comment: Sorry Soma, I'm not asking any API specific questions. I'm asking about the process.